# C printf printing random number

Tags: c, printf

I am very new to C Programming and have a doubt... I've been asked to find errors in certain segments of C code... and this segment has me a bit confused so would appreciate the help...

```
int main(void)     
{
    int myInt = 5;
    printf("myInt = %d");
    return 0;
}
```

As far as i understand there is nothing wrong in this code. What i wanna know is why is this statement printing out a random number ??

The output i get is

```
myInt = 1252057154
```

Would appreciate the help... Thanks

Comment: Take a closer look at your `printf()` call and ask yourself, how does it know which value you want to print?

Comment: The relevant part of the prototype is the dots :) `int printf(const char *fmt, ...);`

Comment: What you need to understand with programming is that computer does not magic and is not intelligent. It does **only** what you tell it. If you don't tell `printf` to print `myInt`, how is it going to know what number you expect it to print? If you had two `int`s in your program, which one did you mean to print?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read more about *C* programming.

And you should enable all warnings and debugging when compiling. With GCC, this means `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (on Linux at least).

When compiling with

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g john.c -o john
```

I am getting the following warnings:

```
john.c: In function ‘main’:
john.c:4:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
john.c:4:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
john.c:4:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat]
john.c:3:9: warning: unused variable ‘myInt’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

So the correction is simple:

```
/* file john.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)     
{
  int myInt = 5;
  printf("myInt = %d\n", myInt);
  return 0;
}
```

which gets compiled without warnings.

Notice the `\n` at the end of `printf` format string. It is important.

Always **enable all the warnings the compiler can give you** and trust the compiler, so correct your code till no warnings is given.

And **learn to use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb` on Linux).

The behavior you observed is **undefined behavior**; *anything* could happen with a *standard conforming implementation* of *C* (even an explosion).

Happy hacking.

Answer (score 4):

`printf` (and similarly scanf) works like this:

Let's say you issue a call to `printf`

```
printf("%d some text %f %u %hu some more text\n", arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

`printf` goes over the format string and replaces `%?` with an argument, based on `?`

```
%d some text %f %u %hu some more text
 |           |   |  |
arg1       arg2  |  arg4
                arg3
```

Now the thing with functions taking variable number of arguments is that, they don't know if the arguments exist, that's why they just take data from a specific part of the stack based on the format string. If you write:

```
printf("%d %f %u\n");
```

it reads three non existing data from the stack, most probably get the values stored when calling the function (values that should be hidden from you)

Answer (score 2):

It should be this:

```
printf("myInt = %d",myInt);
```

If you don't include the variable, then it basically pulls a random chunk of memory in. In addition, it might cause more wierd stuff to happen if you do this with a larger chunk of code. Always make sure that you have as many variables from a printf statement as you need, or bad stuff will result.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if it's printing something wrong, the problem is in the `printf` call:

```
printf("myInt = %d");
```

Which arguments you're expected to pass?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)     
{
    int myInt = 5;
    printf("myInt = %d",myInt);
    return 0;
}
```

The only change in the code is I added myInt variable in the printf statement if you see at the end.Whenever a variable is assigned some value it can be displayed only by passing it to the printf() function with the corresponding type specifier.Its a rule in C.

Comment: Good, but lacks an explanation, for a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

printf is a function that receives one or more arguments.
In your case it received only one argument (which is legal) but the argument containes %d which tells printf to take the second argument instead of the %d.
printf takes the "second argument" from the stack, and because only one argument was pushed to the stack (the string), it uses the return address as the second argument.